# Vertically Center title page : Article

Tags: titles

How can I vertically center the text on a title page ?

---

**My MWE :**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\title{Project Title}
\date{2016-31-01}
\author{Author Name}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to reopen this but is there a way to do this while also centering an abstract below the title?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do that with the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\title{Project Title}
\date{2016-31-01}
\author{Author Name}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{titling}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\null\mbox{}\vfill}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\null}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked just fine, although why was the `graphicx` package used ?

Comment: Oh! For nothing. I started with an existing preamble, and didn't notice I had forgotten to remove it. There's also a spurious `amsymb`. It's removed from the code now.

Comment: So then I wouldn't need these lines as well right ? `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{sendak.jpg}
\vfill PUBLISHING HOUSE}`

Comment: Good gracious! One more forgotten..  You can safely remove it (unless you want some funny effect…)

Comment: I don't understand the mess in the code I posted. I guessed it's a problem with my clipboard manager. Please see the corrected code, which is very short.

Comment: Sure, this code is much simpler to comprehend. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I know some time has passed, but there is a simpler solution. You just need to use "titlepage" in the documentclass:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}

\begin{document} \
\begin{titlepage} \
\title{test} \
\author{testauthor} \
\maketitle \
\end{titlepage} \
\end{document}
```

Comment: what are all the ``\ `` for?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the title is still at the top of the page.